# Download a file in ionic gives error like error code 1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, file-transfer

I am using ionic-file-trasnfer in my ionic project I use same as documentation like following :-

```
download() {
  const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
}
```

But, I got error code 1.. It goes in error callback function not in success callback

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new filetransfer object into this function. Kindly find below code

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';

constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File, private fileOpener: FileOpener) { }

...
download() {

 const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
 const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
     this.fileOpener.open(entry.toURL(), 'application/pdf')
  .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
```

For opening file you have to add  fileOpener plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/), i just updated code kindly review it.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I tried same but didn't working!! Does It issue of version (Ionic Version or any other thing) ?

Comment: It go in success callback.. But, It will not opened file

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { DocumentViewer} from '@ionic-native/document-viewer';
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
import {Toast} from '@ionic-native/toast';

constructor(private document:DocumentViewer, private file: File, private transfer: FileTransfer, private toast: Toast){}

.....

public download() {
        let path = null;
            if(this.platform.is('ios')){
                path = this.file.documentsDirectory;
            }else if(this.platform.is('android')){
                path = this.file.dataDirectory;
            }
            const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
            fileTransfer.download('http://www.example.com/file.pdf',path + 'file.pdf').then((entry)=>{
                let url = entry.toURL();
                this.toast.show('Download Complted', '5000','center').subscribe(
                    toast=>{
                        console.log(toast);
                    }
                );
                this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
            });
        }
```

I've edited your code a bit, you can take a look at this code. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried same but didn't working!! Does It issue of version (Ionic Version or any other thing) ?

Comment: It comes Download Complted.. But, It will not opened file

Comment: I used the same code, but it work fine for me bro.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kM4cCQn8Bz4, you may try watch this video for better understanding.

Comment: Yes, I also follow that video but,It didn't work for me